# Pycharm says that s.listen(2) is an invalid argument. How can I fix that?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working on creating a multi-player game using pygame and socket. I have followed the online tutorials made by TechwithTim (website: http://techwithtim.net/tutorials/python-online-game-tutorial/server/). Upon completion of the second portion of the tutorial, in which he codes the server of the game, and one continuous issue I have with the program is that it calls the argument "s.listen(2)" and sometimes the program states that it is an invalid argument, and other times it doesn't. Most of the time it calls it an invalid argument, and even when i copy and paste the code directly from TechfromTim's website, it still calls it an invalid argument (even though this doesn't happen in the tutorial. Thoughts on how I can resolve this?

I have already tries uninstalling and reinstalling Pycharm but nothing works. For you reference, I will attach an image of the code

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not image.

Comment: What is `str(e)` supposed to do? Did you mean `print(str(e))`?

Comment: It sounds like PyCharm has gotten confused about what `s` is. It can show you what it thinks `s.listen()` is and what the parameters should be. What does it show?

Comment: no, I didn't mean print(str(e)). It is meant to take e, which is the error, and print it onto the screen as a string

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to do that...how do I do that?

Comment: `print(str(e))` is how you print it onto the screen. Just putting `str(e)` doesn't print it.

Comment: I don't see any warning or error on the screenshot, do you receive the error while script is running?

Comment: @user2235698 yes I do. It says it on the bottom window. It is not visible on the screenshot I sent but yes

Comment: @Barmar do you think that was why the program kept listing  s.listen as an error?

Comment: No, they shouldn't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: @SarveshSundaram it means that method is used inappropriately, here is nothing to do with PyCharm, PyCharm just starts your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
host = socket.gethostname() 
s.bind((host, port))         
s.listen(2)
```

Try to get the host name and bind them this way, it works for me.